# Binaries for gnu tar and gnu gzip

Tags: tar, gzip

I would like to know where i can download the binaries for **gnu** tar and **gnu** gzip for various platforms ( `aix64, hp64, hpia64, intel, linia32, linia64, linx64, solus64, solx64, winx64`)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally they're compiled within the OS in question or installed from vendor-supplied packages rather than being installed precompiled from tarballs or some other form of download from GNU. You'll probably need to get a copy of the operation system in order to build or acquire them.

Comment: I am not sure! I have downloaded the gnu tar and gnu gzip for winx64, and could not find others. I need to extend my program on all platforms. So i need to use the binaries

Comment: It's not strange on a *nix platform to tell the user that they need to have suchandsuch a system tool already installed. Just invoke it via `gtar` and check for failure to run it.

Comment: I am not worried about the ones in OS. I would like to know the binaries which i can use to tar the files in various platforms.

Comment: Use `gtar` and `gzip`. Make it a requirement of *nix systems that they be installed. Your users will only get angry if you throw at them some binary which may or may not work depending on their system configuration, so make it their problem. They can handle it, really.